# How to solve "invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start." when building a container Ubuntu 14.04 and installing apache2?

Tags: apache, docker

I am trying to install apache2 after a building image process.
This is the code I am using in the Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get install -y apache2
```

After the process I get the apache installed but I get the follow error (red display in terminal)

```
...
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
...
```

How to solve that issue? If it is an issue.

Comment: Does the build fail or its just a text you see during build?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/06/policy-rc-d-do-not-start-services-automatically/) is a good post which tries to root cause the issue you are facing.

**Shorter way**:

1. `RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` should resolve your issue
   OR
2. If that doesn't resolve the issue, try running your docker container with `privileged` option. Like this, `docker run --privileged -d -ti DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG`

Ideally, I would not recommend running container with `privileged` option unless it's a test bed container. The reason being running a docker container with privileged gives all capabilities to the container, and it also lifts all the limitations enforced. In other words, the container can then do almost everything that the host can do. But this is not a good practice. This defeats the docker purpose of isolating from host machine.

The ideal way to do this is to `set capabilities` of your docker container based on what you want to achieve. Googling this should help you out to provide appropriate `capability` for your docker container.

Comment: `echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0"` won't work, use `printf "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0"`

Comment: @ANTARA it would be good to say why the echo won't work.  I presume because of the \n.

Comment: @TimBird Yes, because of the `\n` that won't be evaluated correctly in echo. If you need to use echo, add `-e` flag (enables interpretation of backslash escapes). Please note `-e` param may not exist on all *nix OS.

Comment: So just to be crystal clear this is to be run on the host machine and not from the Dockerfile / docker run script?

Comment: @Austin It needs to be run inside the container, before installing apache. Generally that'd mean adding it to the Dockerfile, unless you're installing apache from a run script.

Comment: Another Docker one-liner (with chmod support): `RUN bash -c "install -m755 <(printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0') /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d"`

Comment: this command helped me i solve problems with virtualbox on ubuntu 20.04
the command used here `printf '#!/bin/sh\nexit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` could not run even with sudo, I had to be root (sudo su) to run it.

Comment: The first option helped me to solve the issue while running a Linux instance in a docker container. Thanks!

Comment: Does first option opens any security holes?

Answer (score 0):

worked for me after adding in Dockerfile:

RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel

- Starting NTP server ntpd
  ...done.

Answer (score 0):

Working on Ubuntu 23.04 and starting from the blog post linked to by @StackzOfZtuff and @Nikhil Katre above, I used a slightly different pair of methods. Firstly, I added this line into my `Dockerfile`, which gets rid of the `could not determine current runlevel` message.

```
ENV RUNLEVEL 1
```

Secondly, I edited `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` from its default, to allow Apache reloads but not anything else:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "apache2" ]
then
    exit 0
fi
exit 101
```

By the way, a trap for the unwary: comments on the second line of the file seemed to break it. I don't really understand why, but be sure not to put them in.