# How do I resolve 'The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist' error in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed virtual box in my device using `sudo apt install virtualbox-qt` command.

But when I run `virtualbox` command or `virtualbox --version` command it gives me this error:

> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.     Please
> install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate    headers,
> most likely linux-headers-generic.
>
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.

I searched a solution from the internet but it didn't work for me. How should I solve this?

**update**

when I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms` U receive this error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 51):

It clearly states that you need to install the `virtualbox-dkms` packages. You can follow these steps to solve the problem.

- Install the virtualbox-dkms

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
```

- Once you install those packages you also need to do the reconfiguration:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
```

- If your problem is still not fixed try installing the headers:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

You can refer to this [Virtualbox Wiki](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads#Debian-basedLinuxdistributions) if any of the above won't work. Also, you may want to check [this similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465454/problem-with-the-installation-of-virtualbox) on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when i run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms ` i received an error. i updated the screenshot above. kindly request you to check it

Comment: This was helpful. In my case I had to update my gcc before running these commands. @F.A.SULAIMAN this might be your issue as well.

Comment: the reconfiguration failed with the above screenshot

Comment: I went for KVM2, easy to install and working like a charm : https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/kvm2/

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox` might return the error `invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of restart.` it can be fixed thanks to the following answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247032/how-to-solve-invoke-rc-d-policy-rc-d-denied-execution-of-start-when-building

the command used there could not run even with `sudo`, I had to be root (`sudo su`) to run it. my system is ubuntu focal

Comment: the messages do say to install this and that, but doing the dpkg-reconfigure ... actually fixed my problem

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

Comment: How do you know if it will locate the package?
Any chance that you know if a package is available for windows ubuntu subsystem aka. 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft  ?

Comment: Fails with an error: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

Answer (score 10):

The only thing that helped in my case was disabling the Ubuntu Secure Boot

I will quote an answer from Askubuntu:"You might have a kernel version greater than 4.4.0-20 which enforces that unsigned kernel modules are not to be allowed to run with Secure Boot enabled in BIOS"

Link to the Answer:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/777308/virtualbox-problem-kernel-module-is-not-loaded"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777308/virtualbox-problem-kernel-module-is-not-loaded%22)

Link how to disable Secure Boot:
http://itadminguide.com/disable-secure-boot-in-ubuntu/

After this you will most likely have another error but with Minikube, and to fix you'll have to Enable enable Virtualization in Bios

link: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/5456

Comment: disabling secure boot worked for me. Thanks